# How do you pass different collections through the same parameter?

Tags: collections, parameter-passing, watin

I am creating a method that will take a collection of different types  (divs, spans..) and search it. I can't find a parameter to pass different collection types though. I tried IElementContainer and ElementCollections but I can't cast DivCollection to either. Is there another way?

The method that does the search:

```
    private static ElementCollection searchCollections(IElementContainer ec, WACore.compStringInfo info)
    {
        if (info.componentIDName == WACore.componentIDs.Id.ToString())
        {
            return ec.Elements.Filter(Find.ById(info.componentIDValue));                                
        }
        else if (info.componentIDName == WACore.componentIDs.Name.ToString())
        {
            return ec.Elements.Filter(Find.ByName(info.componentIDValue));
        }
        else if (info.componentIDName == WACore.componentIDs.Title.ToString())
        {
            return ec.Elements.Filter(Find.ByTitle(info.componentIDValue));
        }
        else if (info.componentIDName == WACore.componentIDs.OuterText.ToString())
        {                
            String str = info.componentIDValue.Substring(1, 6);
            return ec.Elements.Filter(Find.ByText(new Regex(str)));                
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The caller(s):

```
   return searchCollections((IElementContainer)doc.TextFields, info);
   return searchCollections((IElementContainer)(doc.Divs), info); 
   return searchCollections((IElementContainer)doc.Spans, info);
```

Comment: Post your method code for example.

Comment: As i can see SpanCollection  and DivCollection extends BaseElementCollection, may simply need to specify one parameter in the method  - BaseElementCollection.

Comment: Thanks, I posted the code. The way it is, I get a casting error at runtime where the search method is called. I looked at the BaseElementCollection the other day but it requires that a type be specified. The search parameter need to generically accept any element collection (Divs, Spans...)

Comment: PS: What Im trying to accomplish is to create a way to find element(s) given the element type ex:Div and an attribute ex; Id="myDiv"

Comment: doc its a IElementContainer? you get from him Divs collection and cast it to IElementContainer ? maybe just searchCollections(doc.Elements, info);

Comment: Doc is a browser so doc.Divs  would be the Div collection of the browser.  Passing doc.Elements would pass the entire collection of Doc. That would be a good idea but I was trying to narrow the search by just passing the desired type of element. Ex; doc.Divs. I don't think there is a collection type or interface that is common to all individual element collections. In other words, it looks like  you cant pass doc.Divs and doc.Textfields through a common parameter like IElementContainer. This would be a useful way to use the same search code on different types of collections.

Comment: Unless there is a watin method that will allow you to search by specifying the parent container, type of element and criteria.

Comment: If you are querying for an HTML tag by Id, there should never be more than one tag on the page by that Id. If there is, you first need to fix your HTML.